# Is there a way to print dynamic variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, dynamic, equals

I am coding in node.js atm. I need to create a dynamic variable and invoke it.

e.g.:

```
username = 'im_a_user';

global['ws[' + username + ']'] = ws; //(yes, i want to store the connection with ws module)
```

but

```
ws[im_a_user].send('blabla');
```

doesn't work and node shuts down. So I want to know how `global['ws[' + username + ']']` looks like for debbuging.

---

Do you know how I can print it - or even better, why `im_a_user` in `ws[im_a_user].send('blabla');` isn't defined?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `im_a_user` is not the variable name you want to use, wrap it with quotes, or use the previously defined variable `username`.

Comment: *facepalm* - the quotes... It all makes sence now :D! It worked for me. You don't know how happy I am. Thx a lot - I mean A LOT xD

Comment: Additionally, the dot notation will also work: `ws.im_a_user.send(...);`.

Comment: Thx again, for the information! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Accessing object property is possible with brackets, but you have to give it a valid expression: a string literal or a variable. Looks like you are referencing a variable that is not defined. That's where Node chokes.

So try either with a variable that is defined

```
var key = 'im_a_user'
ws[key].send('blabla');
```

or a string literal

```
ws['im_a_user'].send('blabla');
```